# Bypassing HTTP basic auth locally

Tags: proxy, basic-authentication, socat

I have two applications which I cannot change:

A: provides a URL protected by HTTP basic auth.
B: needs to access this URL but does not support basic auth.
Credentials are available.

How can I make my two applications work together?

I thought a local proxy might be great which injects the authentication. E.g. using socat:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:81,reuseaddr,fork TCP:UrlToA:80,<inject-basic-auth>=user:pass
```

However, socat does not provide an option like < inject-basic-auth >. Anybody knows any tool that might help? Any other way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set up a HTTP reverse proxy server that does the authentication for you. No need to hack any software.

Your reverse proxy listens on some socket (e.g. proxy:8080) and forwards requests to your actual application A, inserting the headers.

`client_B ----> http://proxy:8080 -----> http://server_A:80`

Nginx is lightweight, high performance and easy to set up. And it's easy to find docs online for what you want. 
See for example http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy

Comment: Bingo! And it also supports auth_basic. That's what I was looking for!

Comment: Link is broken. Is it possible to add the headers using fiddler. All our company computers run fiddler already so this would be great. Is there a guide somewhere on how to do this. I have been looking for a while now I cannot find a lot of information.

Answer (score -1):

This problem seems to be very specific. So you probably won't find a ready-to-use tool.

If you want to do it yourself, your best approach is probably to extend socat:

http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/download/socat-1.7.2.2.tar.gz

Good luck!